# Monitor apache james mail server with javaSimon

Tags: java, performance, servlets, monitoring, james

I would like to montior a running james server with java simon.
Following the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/javasimon/wiki/WebConsole) I would need a war application already running so I can just register the JavaSimon Console Servlet.

That is great and works wonderful with war applications, but since james is a jar, how could I integrate both? Is there a way james deploys internally a servlet container? I saw some discussions about it in the mailing list, but I don't know the current status.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way you can add something into a `web.xml`? Does james server provide any kind of web interface? If not then it is difficult to use Java Simon servlet - you'd have to find a way how to start some embedded web server in it.

If there is a web application you can hook to, use https://github.com/virgo47/javasimon/blob/master/console-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml as a template and instead of the `javasimon-console-webapp` artifact use `javasimon-console-embed` that just provides the classes (servlet, etc) and all the resources. WAR project is really just a WAR wrapper, all is in that embed project.